# ¿Cómo me conecto a una BD de MySql, con Xamp, que no cree yo, a netBeans JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, java-swing, xampp

Necesito conectarme a una base de datos existente, esta BD la hizo un compañero de estudios,estamos haciendo un trabajo juntos en JAVA con NetBeans, para crear la conexión usó Xamp, pero ahora me toca hacer mi parte y no tengo idea si me puedo conectar a la base de datos que el hizo... y como hacerlo

Comment: Tienes que revisar las configuraciones, el puerto, el usuario, password etc.  xampp lo unico que hace eso es levantar el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a escribir algunas preguntas ya que no se el entorno que tenéis y las voy a ir respondiendo para que te sirva de ayuda y puedas hacerte una idea de que tienes que hacer.

**¿ El compañero que ha hecho la base de datos, creo la base de datos en su equipo ?**

- Si este el caso, lamento decirte que no puedes conectarte a la DB, tienes que pedir a tu compañero que te exporte la DB y luego tu la importes en tu equipo.
- Otra solución es que tu compañero haga "visible" la DB en la red local, o bien a través de internet (cosa que no recomiendo si es un desarrollo)

**¿Quieres conectarte a la DB desde Java o desde Xampp?**

- Como veo que usáis MySQL te recomiendo usar el programa de MySQL Workbench para tratar con la base de datos antes que usar Xampp, este último lo puedes usar para iniciar el servicio de MySQL.
- Y si quieres conectarte desde Java te dejo un link con la documentación del driver JDBC https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html